# Combine C and C++ in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have the following makefile stub. As you can see, I'm trying to pass all .cpp and .c files to the same command line. But I get `asdf.c:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.` I've verified that there are tabs instead of spaces. The error only occurs when I try to combine the C++ and C. Can I make it work?

```
SRC      := $(shell find . -name "*.cpp") $(shell find . -name "*.c")
OBJ      := boot.o $(SRC:.cpp=.o) $(SRC:.c=.o)

%.o: %.cpp %.c
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

The error only seems to be when I use a `.c` file. For example:

```
SRC      := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ      := boot.o $(SRC:.c=.o)

%.o: %.c
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

gives the same error.

or `SRC      := $(shell find . -name "*.cpp") asdf.c`

The makefile works completely fine until the c file shows up. I've verified this file is the problem because `touch test.c` and then added `test.c` to `SRC` doesn't cause an error.

What could my `.c` file possibly do to cause make an error?

Comment: You have a `.o` file that needs to be compiled from *both* a `.cpp` **and** a `.c` file? Because that's what that rule says. That aside combining those files (whatever you mean by that exactly) can't cause that error. That error means a missing tab or tabs/spaces where they aren't supposed to be. Make sure you don't have a leading tab on the blank line and *do* have one on the recipe line.

Comment: I've confirmed with `cat -t -e -v`. And no, I want both .cpp and .c to be compiled to their own object files.

Comment: A word of caution: Be sure to use a C++ compiler/linker to link the code if you're mixing C and C++. I have seen strange behaviour (Exe crashes on SIGILL on 3rd party C API call but only if using POSIX timezone) when C and C++ were linked with C linker. Turns out the API provider were linking with C++ library code. The problem went away when using C++ to link and it took quite a bit of effort to track the problem down.

Comment: Yes I'm using a C++ compiler, as evidenced by CXX.

Comment: The target `%.o: %.cpp %.c` says build a file `%.o` from a `%.cpp` **and** a `%.c` file. Not either a `%.cpp` *or* a `%.c` file.

Comment: Is that snippet the *entire* makefile? What files are in the current directory? What does running `make` by itself output?